# Consume String from Kafka Topic

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a question regarding consuming JSON String from Kafka: Do I need to add a Config class for my consumer for Deserialization if I'm just consuming a String and then mapping it to a DTO?

```
@Service
public class Consumer   {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Consumer.class);


@Autowired
OBTMapper obtMapper;

@KafkaListener(topics = "foo" , groupId = "group_id")
public void receive(String message) {

    //Map String to DTO
    obtMapper.Mapper(message);
    logger.info("Message received %s", message);
    

}
```

When do I have to add this config class in general? I know that when I want to send an object I need to serialize it first in the Producer config and send it and then deserialize it in the consumer but do I also need that if I'm just producing a String and consuming it afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

Only binary data pass through Kafka, so yes, we must always serialize when producing and deserialize when consuming.

Comment: Okay because I saw somewhere that adding the serializer is only necessary when we are sending JSON objects, for raw String it's not necessary.

Comment: @Jsefbch Both json (which is still a string) and plain strings are stored in UTF8 encoded binary, for example, so yes, you need serializers defined, even if there's defaults

Comment: I tried to consume a JSON String and map it to a dto object and it worked without a config class for deserializion. Do you have an idea why? @OneCricketeer

Comment: @Jsefbch Spring Kafka has reasonable defaults

Comment: So by default the kafka consumer expects Strings and doesn't need a configuration class unless we are consuming an object? thank you @OneCricketeer

Comment: @Jsefbch No. Kafka only has bytes. Spring client abstracts away some  required configuration

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wire in your own ObjectMapper, but yes, you need a deserializer. Jackson ObjectMapper both *deserializes*  string/bytes **and parses** that, though.

Spring Kafka natively offers JSON deserialization. Then you can use your POJO in the method parameter rather than just a String

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#json-serde